# Can you import a save from Walking Dead Season 1 to Season 2?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one, the-walking-dead-season-two

I recently bought Walking Dead Season 2.  I remember hearing that Season 2 might import your decisions from Season 1.  Is this true and if so is there anything I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How Do I Import My Save?**
>
> To import your Season 1 save, you will need to start Season 2 first. To do this, launch Season 2 and continue to the Main Menu. On the Main Menu, select 'Play', then 'Start Episode 1'. This will land you on a page asking if you want to import your Season 1 choices. Select 'Ok' to scan for completed Season 1 saves.
>
> **Complete Season 1 Episodes**
>
> Only completed Season 1 saves will be imported into Season 2. If you have any completed episodes, those choices will import to Season 2, and random choices will be made for any episodes that are unfinished or have not been played. If you've completed all episodes in the series, all your choices will be imported into Season 2.
>
> **Can't Find Season 1 Save?**
>
> Season 2 will look for a completed Season 1 save in the default save directory for Season 1. This directory is located in the C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Telltale Games\The Walking Dead folder on PC, and ~Library/Application Support/Telltale Games on Mac. If these files have been moved or altered, or only the save files (and not the prefs.prop) have been kept, then Season 2 will not find your Season 1 save. Also, the Username determines where the saves are stored. If a different Windows account is being used to play Season 2, the saves for Season 1 will not be found.
>
> **Compatibility Mode/Windows 7 vs XP/98**
>
> Some users may have played Season 1 in Compatibility Mode on a Windows Vista or 7 computer. Windows Vista and 7 use the save directory C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Telltale Games\The Walking Dead. All previous Windows OS, including XP and 98, use C:\Users\%Username%\My Documents\Telltale Games\The Walking Dead as the save directory. If Season 2 is unable to find your Season 1 saves, it may be looking in the wrong directory. Due to the way Windows creates new directories in Compatibility Mode, it's not possible to manually create this directory. The only way for Season 2 to see Season 1 saves is to play Season 2 in Compatibility Mode, as well.

Source:
http://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/53784/season-2-save-import-faq-please-read

Answer (score 1):

Series 2 will find your saves from series 1 and 400 days automatically when you start it. If saves are found in the saves directory (`C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Telltale Games\The Walking Dead` folder on PC, and `~/Library/Application Support/Telltale Games` on Mac) or the Steam Cloud, you will be given an option to import them.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't import the save as well. So I turned off the compatibility mode on Season 1 and replayed episode one (some patch must have repaired the issue  because of which I turned it on in the first place). The game created another TellTale folder with all the saves I had (steam cloud sync on). Just copy those saves from the compatibility folder to the new one (it's the one with fewer saves) and Season 2 will be able to detect them. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this problem under Linux when using steam play you can solve it with the following command:

```
cp -r ~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/compatdata/207610/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/My\ Documents/Telltale\ Games/The\ Walking\ Dead ~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/compatdata/261030/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/My\ Documents/Telltale\ Games/The\ Walking\ Dead
```

After that you should be able to import your save into season 2

Comment: This worked for me, I think you might have to restart the game / Steam afterwards.When I first tried this, the loading screen still showed "no results found", but after I rebooted (for different reasons) the game became able to detect the decisions from season 1.

Answer (score 1):

After a whole evening of attempts, i did it: i have macOS, but i think it will work on Windows too just by adapting the folders path.

I noticed that - once I tried one time to start the season 2 and to recover (unsuccessfully) first season's saves - the new season (2) created a new folder named "The Walking Dead 2" in a completely new position: the folder `Documents\Telltale Games` (on macOS).

So i went to `-Library\Application Support\TellTale Games\TheWalkingDead` and copied the whole folder "TheWalkingDead", pasting it in `Documents\Telltale Games`. Then I changed the name of the folder "TheWalkingDead" in "The Walking Dead".

The last thing I did was to re-name the last save file from season 1: in my case it was "save_69.save" and I renamed it "saveslot1.bundle".

Answer (score -1):

Just change the name of the last save file from season 1 to "saveslot1.bundle". Make sure you change the extension to *.bundle and that the folder with Season 1 saves is in the correct place (\Documents\Telltale Games\The Walking Dead).

After that the game should find the save file properly.