# The Walking Dead Season 3 Decisions Import

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one, the-walking-dead-season-two, the-walking-dead-a-new-frontier

So I have pretty limited space on my PC, as in storage. So I frequently delete games after I complete them or just become bored. I finished TWD seasons 1 and 2 but held off on deleting them as I care for the story and remembered that TWD Season 3 will import my decisions. Like i said though, I need the space for other games, so is there a way to delete the games (season 1 and 2) but retain the decisions so when Season 3 asks to import them I'll be able to?

(I have legit copies bought off steam so no torrent, if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't played TWD S3, any "normal" game usually save your progress in a save file, and usually that save file is somewhere in your documents, or perhaps in appdata. When you delete a game on steam it usually only delete the game files in the steam folder, not touching your save files.

Assuming TWD S3 works like S2 (basing myself on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/182566/141481)), you can go ahead and uninstall the previous seasons. Just make a copy of your S1 and S2 saves files beforehands to be extra safe.

Comment: Can confirm that I deleted my season 1 data and still had, like, that one thing carry over into season 2. So we can probably assume that S3 works the same way, but I haven't played it yet so I can't confirm that